# meaning of the phrase "at all" in non-negative sentences?

Tags: meaning

I have come across this use of the phrase in this [video](https://youtu.be/syX-07rhxoE). Here is the piece:

> So if you have been studying English pronunciation **at all**, I am sure
>   you have heard about this schwa sound.

As the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at-all) puts it, the phrase is used in negatives for emphasis. The root of my confusion is that the sentence is not neative. Could you give a similar phrase that would have the same meaning in the sentence.

Comment: *If you have been studying English pronunciation **even a little bit***. There are many contexts where ***at all*** doesn't have to be in a "negating" context. For example, *Descartes said that **if he knew anything at all,** he knew that he existed*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As per the Cambridge Dictionary definition, it is applicable in both negatives and questions. You example is a question.

Comment: @Omegastick: *[**At all costs**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22at+all+costs%22) we should avoid being too restrictive in our definition of "acceptable usage contexts" for the collocation*. :) Besides which, at best you could say the Descartes example is a "rhetorical question", since no-one would dispute that he ***did*** know something!

Comment: @FumbleFingers You'll find that the phrase *at all costs* is actually using a different construction. To show that, the *all* can be replaced with *any* (*at any cost*). You can't do that with the phrase *at all*.

Comment: @Omegastick: *The train now leaving platform 7 will be calling **at all** stations to London Victoria.* As I said before, there are many contexts where ***at all*** doesn't have to be in a "negating" context. Pointing out that any examples thereof must inevitably involve "a different construction" (by whatever logic) doesn't really get us anywhere.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The words **at** and **all** can go together outside of the phrase **at all**, which is exactly what you're doing. Your sentence doesn't include the *phrase* **at all** in the same way that *"Gee, Whizz-kid over there is going fast*" doesn't include the phrase **gee whiz**.

Comment: @Omegastick: I think I could give any example at all, and you'd still find something to carp about. Why can't you concede the obvious fact that *not every instance* of the collocation ***at all*** must occur in either a negating or a "question" context?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would find something to *"carp"* about because that's how the phrase works, and any dictionary backs me up (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at_all). As I said in my previous comment, the two words can appear next to eachother without being the *phrase* **at all**.

Answer (score 1):

If you read a bit more carefully (I missed it too at first) the Cambridge Dictionary says *"used to make negatives **and questions** stronger"*.

This case is actually a question because of the **if**:

> So **if** you have been studying English pronunciation at all, I am sure you have heard about this schwa sound.